# Proving the torus is $\mathbb{E}^2 \sqcup_f (\mathbb{S}^1 \vee \mathbb{S}^1)$

Tags: general-topology

In *Topology and Groupoids*, the following argument is mentioned (paraphrased):

> Let $\mathbb{E}^2$ be the closed disk and $T^2$ the torus. By the usual argument of pasting the sides of the square, we have a quotient map $\bar f: \mathbb{E}^2 \to T^2$. Further, we notice that $\bar f(\mathbb{S}^1)=\mathbb{S}^1 \vee \mathbb{S}^1$. Therefore, since $\bar f$ is a quotient map, we conclude that $T^2 \cong \mathbb{E}^2 \sqcup_f (\mathbb{S}^1 \vee \mathbb{S}^1)$, where $f=\bar f | \mathbb{S}^1$.

I've been able to show this result "by hand". I was wondering if there's a nicer, easier way to show this; I think at the last step the author was thinking of some result in particular, but I'm not sure which.

Furthermore, I wonder there's any generalization of this for arbitrary spaces. It seems a similar result is false for a quotient $f:X \to Y$, and a closed $Z \subseteq X$, even if $f$ is a bijection on $X \setminus Z$.

Comment: I think the author was thinking about the usual argument that presents the torus as a quotient space of a square that you can find here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surface_(topology).

Comment: @RobArthan Thanks. However I understood that part, what I'm not getting is how he arrives to the conclusion from it.

Answer (score 0):

There are two general theorems you can apply to this situation:

1. Any surjective continuous function $f : X \to Y$ from a compact space to a Hausdorff space is a quotient map.
2. If $f : X \to Y$ is a quotient map then $f$ induces a homeomorphism whose domain is the quotient space of $X$ modulo the point-inverse decomposition $\{f^{-1}(y) \mid y \in Y\}$ and whose codomain is $Y$.